# How much region can be controlled by performing Rajasuya?

Tags: mahabharata, yajna, yudhisthira, earth, harishchandra

It has been mentioned in Mahabharata that two kings: Yudhistira and Harishchandra performed Rajasuya.

Control of how much region will be gained by performing Rajasuya?  Will it cover the whole earth or a part of the earth?